# Construyendo graficas con bokeh - python

Tags: python, pandas, bokeh

Tengo un error en la linea 23, llevo ya dos horas y aun no doy con el problema, este es un pie chart que muestra la cantidad de hombre y mujeres de mi archivo excel.

```
from math import pi

import pandas as pd

from bokeh.io import output_file, show
from bokeh.palettes import Category20c
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.transform import cumsum

from bokeh.palettes import Spectral6
from bokeh.transform import factor_cmap

output_file("pie.html")
df = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\cisco\Desktop\ProyectoV\transito\homicidios-accidentes-transito-2018_1.xls')

grouped = df.groupby('Sexo')['Cantidad'].sum()
grouped * 100

print(grouped)

data = pd.Series(grouped).reset_index(name='value').rename(columns={'index':'genre'})
data['angle'] = data['value']/data['value'].sum() * 2*pi
data['color'] = Category20c[len(grouped)]

p = figure(plot_height=350, title="Género", toolbar_location=None,
           tools="hover", tooltips="@Sexo: @value", x_range=(-0.5, 1.0))

p.wedge(x=0, y=1, radius=0.4, start_angle=cumsum('angle', include_zero=True), end_angle=cumsum('angle'),
        line_color="white", fill_color='color', legend='Sexo', source=data)

p.axis.axis_label=None
p.axis.visible=False
p.grid.grid_line_color = None

show(p)
```

error

```
File "c:\Users\cisco\Desktop\ProyectoV\transito\genero.py", line 23, in <module>
    data['color'] = Category20c[len(grouped)]
KeyError: 2
```

Comment: Ya que no dispongo de tu archivo excel no puedo reproducir el error, pero lo que te puedo decir es que se debe a que `Category20c` es un diccionario y no tiene la clave `2` a la que intentas acceder (pues `len(grouped)` parece ser 2 en tu caso). Las claves de ese diccionario comienzan en `3`, y llegan hasta `20`.

Comment: Gracias porresponder, no me queda claro. Las columnas con las que boy a trabajar son las siguientes: `print(df['Sexo'],['Cantidad'])`:
`0       FEMENINO
1      MASCULINO
2       FEMENINO
3      MASCULINO`

Comment: Yo no entiendo lo que pretendes con `Category20c`. ¿se trata de asignar diferente color a MASCULINO y FEMENINO? En ese caso insisto, no puedes usar `Category20c` para eso porque son sólo dos categorías y ese diccionario sólo tiene listas de colores para un número de categorías entre 3 y 20.